# How do I eliminate a gap between a box-shadow and a div background when using partially transparent rgba() values

Tags: css, border, background-color, rgba, box-shadow

---

For some reason, when using **partially transparent rgba() background-color** and **box-shadow color values** on an element with a **non-fixed (percent-based) border-radius**, it renders a ***tiny transparent gap*** at the edge of the div element **between the background and the box-shadow**.

---

My quesion is this...

## *How do I get rid of this gap*, while maintaining a non-fixed border-radius with background-color and box-shadow transparency?

---

[image: Gap between box shadow and div background]

Here is the code:

```css
html {
  background-color: #cef;
  font-family: arial;
}
#background-underlay{
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%; 
  padding-top:0px;
  color: black;
}
#overlay-div{
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15%;
  left: 15%;
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 40, 0.8);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2em 2em rgba(0, 0, 40, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="background-underlay">Background Text</h1>
<div id="overlay-div"></div>
```

---

### Description of the sample element:

- I have a `<div>` with a semi-transparent rgba background color and box-shadow.
- Both the background-color and box-shadow color values are set at `rgba(0, 0, 40, 0.8)`.
- The `border-radius` of the div is set to `50%`.

  ---

### Things I've tried which were not successful:

- Adjusting the `spread` value of the box-shadow
- Adding a border to the `div` with a border-color value that is the same `rgba()` as the box-shadow and background color value
- Adding an `inset` box-shadow (produced the same issue)
- Using the same color for `background-color` and `box-shadow` (as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490320/gap-between-border-and-image-when-border-radius-is-added) to a related question)
- Attempting to manually apply a 1px "overlay" border with the same `rgba()` color using a **separate element** (I tried the `::before` element) to "cover" the gap. (I could not position it to match up perfectly with the gap, and even with a border-width of just 1px, it renders wider than the transparent gap I am trying to cover). Based this off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948939/box-shadow-and-border-rendering-bug) to a related question.

---

### Things which (at least partially) removed the gap, which are *not* solutions:

- ***I am*** able to eliminate it if I use the same **solid** (non-transparent) color value for both, **but that is not a solution**, since I lose transparency.
- Changing the `opacity` property value is also **not a solution**, because that interferes with the transparency of any content that would be nested within the div (such as images or text), which is the reason for going through the trouble of using `rgba()` instead of `opacity` in the first place.
- Lastly, changing the `border-radius` value from percentage to fixed (px or em) *does help*, but depending on the value, often this will still produce the gap. So this too is **not a solution**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A blur filter can give you the same output or at least a similar one without issue:

```css
html {
  background-color: #cef;
  font-family: arial;
}
#background-underlay{
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%; 
  padding-top:0px;
  color: black;
}
#overlay-div{
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 8%;
  left: 8%;
  height: 81%;
  width: 81%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 40, 0.8);
  filter:blur(1.5em);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="background-underlay">Background Text</h1>
<div id="overlay-div"></div>
```