# How to make circle area transparent/see-through?

Tags: css, transparent

To be able to see through to the other side what I want to do is make the circle area transparent so you are able to see through to the background image.

How would this be done?

Is there a way to do that?

https://jsfiddle.net/r95sy2fw/

This image is what I am trying to replicate in the code.

How do I make it transparent like that?

[image]

**The snippet I provided** currently looks like this:

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;

  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b)70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-content: center;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 642px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0px 0px #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  background: #0a0a0a;
}

.fence {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10" ><path stroke="rgb(113, 121, 126)" d="m10 .15-4.85 4.85 4.85 4.85v.15h-.13l-4.86-4.86-4.86 4.86h-.15v-.14l4.87-4.86-4.87-4.87v-.13h.15l4.86 4.86 4.85-4.86h.14z"/></svg>');
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #000);
  clip-path: circle(25% at center);
  animation: fade 8s linear;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.9;

  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}

.fence>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 20%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 30%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(4) {
  top: 40%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(5) {
  top: 50%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(6) {
  top: 60%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(7) {
  top: 70%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(8) {
  top: 80%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(9) {
  top: 90%;
}

.fan svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  animation: fan-spin 100s linear;
}

@keyframes fan-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.cross::before,
.cross::after {
  content: "";
  background: black;
}

.cross::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  clip-path: circle(29% at center);
}

.cross::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: circle(51% at center);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="curtain ">
     <div class="ratio-keeper">
       <div class="fence">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>

       <div class="fan">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70%" height="70%" viewBox="76 130 381 381">
           <path fill="#000100" stroke="#000" d="m166.3352 168.6294c5.5396 2.4448 45.2339 54.394 72.7499 91.0151-9.1901-44.8757-21.7959-109.0279-19.9558-114.796 4.1462-12.9949 33.7039-13.5172 41.5845-13.7579 7.8827-.2415 37.4165-1.5221 42.3488 11.1948 2.1872 5.6436-6.4773 70.4506-12.9142 115.8007 25.2309-38.2323 61.6818-92.5089 67.0612-95.2865 12.119-6.2568 33.3898 14.2749 39.1337 19.6768 5.7424 5.402 27.5341 25.3815 22.0294 37.859-2.4441 5.5389-54.3954 45.2354-91.0172 72.7506 44.8757-9.1901 109.0293-21.7959 114.7974-19.9559 12.9927 4.1442 13.5193 33.7032 13.7586 41.5838.2422 7.8819 1.5221 37.4165-11.192 42.3473-5.6471 2.1894-70.4541-6.4765-115.8049-12.9127 38.2323 25.2323 92.5081 61.6783 95.2871 67.0605 6.2581 12.1175-14.2742 33.3877-19.6776 39.133-5.4027 5.7432-25.3815 27.5341-37.8563 22.0279-5.5396-2.4434-45.2361-54.3961-72.7534-91.0143 9.1901 44.8757 21.7952 109.0287 19.9551 114.7953-4.1434 12.9934-33.7026 13.5157-41.5852 13.7586-7.8799.24-37.4165 1.5221-42.3431-11.1936-2.1887-5.6464 6.4779-70.4541 12.9133-115.8071-25.2323 38.2323-61.6824 92.5124-67.0639 95.2908-12.1169 6.256-33.3891-14.2728-39.1337-19.6754-5.7432-5.4027-27.5313-25.383-22.0251-37.8578 2.4434-5.5396 54.394-45.2339 91.0136-72.7526-44.8764 9.1908-109.0266 21.7944-114.7967 19.9566-12.9934-4.1434-13.5171-33.7025-13.7586-41.5852-.2407-7.8806-1.5221-37.4165 11.1963-42.346 5.6443-2.1879 70.4498 6.4752 115.8 12.9121-38.233-25.2316-92.5081-61.6783-95.2865-67.0612-6.256-12.1169 14.2748-33.3913 19.6768-39.1337 5.4006-5.7438 25.3794-27.5333 37.8584-22.0272z" /></svg>

       </div>
       <div class="cross"></div>

       <div class="sun-wrapper">
         <div class="sun"></div>
       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need add a transparent hole in .curtain class:

```css
.curtain {
  ...
  background: radial-gradient(circle,
      transparent 0% 35%, black 35%);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  --color-a: blue;
  --color-b: black;
  --color-c: red;
  --color-d: black;

  background-size: 165px 165px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 5px, #0000 5px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 10px, #0000 10px 160px, var(--color-b) 160px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 15px, #0000 15px 155px, var(--color-c) 155px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 20px, #0000 20px 150px, var(--color-d) 150px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 25px, #0000 25px 145px, var(--color-a) 145px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 30px, #0000 30px 140px, var(--color-b) 140px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 35px, #0000 35px 135px, var(--color-c) 135px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 40px, #0000 40px 130px, var(--color-d) 130px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 45px, #0000 45px 125px, var(--color-a) 125px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b) 50px, #0000 50px 120px, var(--color-b) 120px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 55px, #0000 55px 115px, var(--color-c) 115px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 60px, #0000 60px 110px, var(--color-d) 110px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-a) 65px, #0000 65px 105px, var(--color-a) 105px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-b) 70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-b)70px, #0000 70px 100px, var(--color-b) 100px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-c) 75px, #0000 75px 95px, var(--color-c) 95px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),
    linear-gradient(90deg, var(--color-d) 80px, #0000 80px 90px, var(--color-d) 90px),

    linear-gradient(var(--color-a), var(--color-a));
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-content: center;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 642px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0px 0px #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  background: radial-gradient(circle,
  transparent 0% 35%, black 35%); /* <------ here */
}

.fence {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10" ><path stroke="rgb(113, 121, 126)" d="m10 .15-4.85 4.85 4.85 4.85v.15h-.13l-4.86-4.86-4.86 4.86h-.15v-.14l4.87-4.86-4.87-4.87v-.13h.15l4.86 4.86 4.85-4.86h.14z"/></svg>');
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px #000);
  clip-path: circle(25% at center);
  animation: fade 8s linear;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.9;

  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
}

.fence>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(2) {
  top: 20%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(3) {
  top: 30%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(4) {
  top: 40%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(5) {
  top: 50%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(6) {
  top: 60%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(7) {
  top: 70%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(8) {
  top: 80%;
}

.fence>div:nth-child(9) {
  top: 90%;
}

.fan svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  animation: fan-spin 100s linear;
}

@keyframes fan-spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.cross::before,
.cross::after {
  content: "";
  background: black;
}

.cross::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  clip-path: circle(29% at center);
}

.cross::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: circle(51% at center);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
   <div class="curtain ">
     <div class="ratio-keeper">
       <div class="fence">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>

       <div class="fan">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70%" height="70%" viewBox="76 130 381 381">
           <path fill="#000100" stroke="#000" d="m166.3352 168.6294c5.5396 2.4448 45.2339 54.394 72.7499 91.0151-9.1901-44.8757-21.7959-109.0279-19.9558-114.796 4.1462-12.9949 33.7039-13.5172 41.5845-13.7579 7.8827-.2415 37.4165-1.5221 42.3488 11.1948 2.1872 5.6436-6.4773 70.4506-12.9142 115.8007 25.2309-38.2323 61.6818-92.5089 67.0612-95.2865 12.119-6.2568 33.3898 14.2749 39.1337 19.6768 5.7424 5.402 27.5341 25.3815 22.0294 37.859-2.4441 5.5389-54.3954 45.2354-91.0172 72.7506 44.8757-9.1901 109.0293-21.7959 114.7974-19.9559 12.9927 4.1442 13.5193 33.7032 13.7586 41.5838.2422 7.8819 1.5221 37.4165-11.192 42.3473-5.6471 2.1894-70.4541-6.4765-115.8049-12.9127 38.2323 25.2323 92.5081 61.6783 95.2871 67.0605 6.2581 12.1175-14.2742 33.3877-19.6776 39.133-5.4027 5.7432-25.3815 27.5341-37.8563 22.0279-5.5396-2.4434-45.2361-54.3961-72.7534-91.0143 9.1901 44.8757 21.7952 109.0287 19.9551 114.7953-4.1434 12.9934-33.7026 13.5157-41.5852 13.7586-7.8799.24-37.4165 1.5221-42.3431-11.1936-2.1887-5.6464 6.4779-70.4541 12.9133-115.8071-25.2323 38.2323-61.6824 92.5124-67.0639 95.2908-12.1169 6.256-33.3891-14.2728-39.1337-19.6754-5.7432-5.4027-27.5313-25.383-22.0251-37.8578 2.4434-5.5396 54.394-45.2339 91.0136-72.7526-44.8764 9.1908-109.0266 21.7944-114.7967 19.9566-12.9934-4.1434-13.5171-33.7025-13.7586-41.5852-.2407-7.8806-1.5221-37.4165 11.1963-42.346 5.6443-2.1879 70.4498 6.4752 115.8 12.9121-38.233-25.2316-92.5081-61.6783-95.2865-67.0612-6.256-12.1169 14.2748-33.3913 19.6768-39.1337 5.4006-5.7438 25.3794-27.5333 37.8584-22.0272z" /></svg>

       </div>
       <div class="cross"></div>

       <div class="sun-wrapper">
         <div class="sun"></div>
       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: There is an issue with the code here: https://i.imgur.com/AM226xo.png

The gradient background is showing through the black background?

Is there a way to fix that?

code: https://jsitor.com/pEKIDh-mc

Comment: Small Desktop (1280 x 1024)
Medium Desktop (1920 x 1080)
Big Desktop (2560 x 1440). You can set it to different views to see.

Comment: If I replace: background: radial-gradient(circle, transparent 0% 35%, #0a0a0a 35%);

With: background: #0a0a0a;

That issue is not there.

Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Do you see what I am talking about, and is there a way to fix that?

Comment: it looks like due to rounding error. add outward shadow to `.ratio-keeper {...; border: 2px solid #333;  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 5px black;}`

Comment: Now it is able to be seen through the box-shadow. https://jsitor.com/0gzKpvDj4 Seen Here: https://i.imgur.com/uUuCa22.png

Comment: You need to play with spread radius increase it. and make blur less.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, the background gradient still comes through it no matter what. I tried what you said: https://cssgenerator.org/box-shadow-css-generator.html

Comment: then use zero blur. https://jsitor.com/0gzKpvDj4 I am not able to see the gap with all desktop settings.

Comment: It's still coming through seen here: https://i.imgur.com/1wMA80W.png It can be set to box-shadow: 0 0 0px 500px black; and it still comes through. Seen Here: https://i.imgur.com/RlGy3K0.png

Comment: which browser and OS are you on? show me the picture of this https://jsitor.com/0gzKpvDj4 use Ctrl+F5 to refresh the page.

Comment: Browser is chrome: https://i.imgur.com/ee579wa.png Moving the window slider left and right I am able to see it.

Comment: It's the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61213486/how-do-i-eliminate-a-gap-between-a-box-shadow-and-a-div-background-when-using-pa

Comment: What is the answer then, what do I need to do? How would I apply the answer to my code?

Comment: there is no clean solution, they couldn't solve it either. You need to put something behind it to make it non transparent https://jsitor.com/0gzKpvDj4  note the `.curtain::before` rule.